# i want to grep [Nodes]:ALL from <topo-ospf-nimo>

Tags: linux, grep

please grep the nodes:all from topo-ospf-nimo 
file content:

```
<topo-igp-nimo>
[Nodes]:ALL
[Interfaces]:ALL
[Ports]:ALL
<topo-ospf-nimo>
[Nodes]:ALL
[Interfaces]:ALL
[Ports]:ALL
<topo-mpls-nimo>
[Nodes]:ALL
[Interfaces]:ALL
[Ports]:ALL
```

i tried 
`grep -E '<topo-ospf-nimo>|\[Nodes\]:ALL'`

but it is giving output as:

```
<topo-ospf-nimo>
[Nodes]:ALL
[Nodes]:ALL
[Nodes]:ALL
[Nodes]:ALL
```

i want my output to be

```
<topo-ospf-nimo>
[Nodes]:ALL
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: done the editsi want my output to be

<topo-ospf-nimo>
[Nodes]:ALL

Comment: Take a look at `man grep` and option `-A`.